# Template download page doesn't work correctly

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I just tried to download ABP template with Angular and only one solution, but downloaded zip package seems contains VUE version instead.

Are others facing the same issue?

Comment: I am trying now.

Comment: yeap you're right. It'll be fixed in a short time... thanks for your patience.

Comment: you're welcome! ;)

Comment: could you try again

Comment: YEP! it's working now! Many thanks!